# Are questions regarding micro-controller appropriate?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I found no site in SE for micro-controller programming. The proposed site for [Embeded systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15961/embedded-system-design-and-development) is closed down due to lack of "good response".

This being a programmers' site, it is the next logical place to ask. However I found too few questions on micro-controllers. So the question :

**Are questions regarding micro-controller appropriate for this site?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think questions about micro-controllers would be more appropriate for [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) than Programmers, they have over [800 micro-controller questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microcontroller), while we only have 1, [yours](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176798/how-to-use-keyword-sbit-in-microcontroller-programming). Also Programmers is more focused on conceptual questions, technical questions about programming (implementation issues, coding tools, etc) belong on Stack Overflow.

You should read [their FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly and browse the site for a while, and if you feel it's a better place for your question, I could migrate it there.

Comment: OK. I assumed programming was the place to ask. Please migrate this question.

Comment: @ved2254 Don't worry about posting here, it's an interesting question and we'll find a better home for it (also the downvote will go away with the migration). It seems though that Stack Overflow is also a good fit for it. Will chat with both sites' mods and see what the more appropriate site is.

Comment: Yeeppii for the new home!

Comment: @ved2254 - we're Programm*ers* not Programm*ing*. Coding questions should go to [SO].

Comment: @YannisRizos I'd appreciate it more if you contact area51 mods to re-open embedded systems. Will help many people.

Comment: @ved2254 Hm, that's something you could do yourself by posting a question in the [Area51 discussion zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/). Also Area51 doesn't have mods, it's [moderated directly by Stack Exchange](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/who-are-moderators-on-area51). But you should also give Electrical Engineering a chance, they have tons of questions on embedded systems, I don't see much point in a more specialized site.

Comment: The point is that electrial focuses on connections while stack overflow  on coding. I need equal collaboration of both. Still, thanks, I might just get the answer in electrical.

Comment: @ved2254 Well it's not really my field, so I can't really say if a site on embedded systems would be useful or not, you should make a case for it on the Area51 discussion zone.